# Add a custom function to the JWT Token validation

Tags: c#, authentication, asp.net-core, jwt

I am working on a project in ASP.NET Core which I am using JWT tokens to authenticate users.

I have configured the `JWTBearerDefaults` in my `Startup.cs` file as following:

```
services.AddAuthentication(JwtBearerDefaults.AuthenticationScheme)
 .AddJwtBearer(options =>
 {
     options.TokenValidationParameters = new TokenValidationParameters
     {
         ValidateIssuer = true,
         ValidateAudience = true,
         ValidateLifetime = true,
         ValidateIssuerSigningKey = true,
         ValidIssuer = "some.issuer",
         ValidAudience = "some.issuer",
         ClockSkew = TimeSpan.Zero,
         IssuerSigningKey = new SymmetricSecurityKey(
             Encoding.UTF8.GetBytes(Configuration["SecurityKey"])),
     };

     options.EventsType = typeof(CustomJwtBearerEvents);
 });
```

My requirement is, whenever an API call is received, i should be able to get the token and do some validations. For each method in my API Controller, I can check for the token and perform the validations, but I want that validation to be called from a single place. So for that purposes, on the top code I added `options.EventsType` line.

But the problem is, as soon as I added this line, all the API calls fail because the server throws a `500 internal server error`, and also a `CORS policy` error. But everything works fine without this line.

This is the error that I get in my client browser:

- `Failed to load resource: the server responded with a status of 500 (Internal Server Error)`
- `Access to XMLHttpRequest at 'http://localhost:58402/api/User/GetAllDurations' from origin 'http://localhost:56040' has been blocked by CORS policy: Response to preflight request doesn't pass access control check: No 'Access-Control-Allow-Origin' header is present on the requested resource.`

Any ideas, why this is happening? Is there any other mechanism to achieve this goal?

Comment: Did you try instantiating JwtBearerEvents and setting your validation there instead of using a custom events type?

Comment: @juunas I am still a beginner in using JWT tokens. I would be glad if you could tell me how it can be done in Startup.cs

Comment: I think it's something like `options.Events = new JwtBearerEvents {  }`. Then you can use IntelliSense to figure out what event properties are available there :)

Comment: @juunas Thank you very much. This actually helped me.

Answer (score 2):

You can do that by implementing ISecurityTokenValidator interface.

```
public class MySecurityTokenValidator : ISecurityTokenValidator
{
        public ClaimsPrincipal ValidateToken(string securityToken, TokenValidationParameters validationParameters, out SecurityToken validatedToken)
        {
           //// Perform your custom validation here.
        }
}
```

In Startup, you will have to configure this new logic as below:

```
        var bearerOptions = new JwtBearerOptions();
        bearerOptions.SecurityTokenValidators.Add(new MySecurityTokenValidator(app.ApplicationServices, Encoding.UTF8.GetBytes("SecurityKey1234567890")));
        app.UseJwtBearerAuthentication(bearerOptions);
```

You can refer [this blog for custom implementation.](https://www.frakkingsweet.com/plain-and-simple-token-authentication-in-asp-net-core/)

Answer (score 0):

Have you registered the `CustomJwtBearerEvents` class in the Dependency Injection container? You could do so like:

```cs
services.AddTransient<CustomJwtBearerEvents>();
```

You need this because the ASP.NET Core authentication handler tries to instantiate your custom type from the container, as you can see [in the code on GitHub](https://github.com/aspnet/AspNetCore/blob/62351067ff4c1401556725b401478e648b66acdc/src/Security/Authentication/Core/src/AuthenticationHandler.cs#L95-L103).

Also, if the `CustomJwtBearerEvents` class has constructor dependencies, those also need to be registered in the DI container.